# How to print every element in array in loop if with different types of element?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this phone class:

```
   public class Phone {
        private int id;
        private String brand;
        private String model;
        private int cameraResolution;
        
    public Phone(int id, String brand, String model, int cameraResolution) {
        this.id=id;
        this.brand=brand;
        this.model=model;
        this.cameraResolution= cameraResolution;
    }
    
        public void showDetails() {
            System.out.println("id "+ this.id);
            System.out.println("Marka to "+ this.brand);
            System.out.println("Model to "+ this.model);
            System.out.println("Rozdzielczosc aparatu to " + this.cameraResolution);    
        }
    
and this main class

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone galaxy= new Phone(1, "Samsung","Galaxy",12);
        Phone lumia= new Phone(2, "Nokia","Lumia",13);
        Phone pixel= new Phone(3, "Google","Pixel",14);
        
    galaxy.showDetails();
    
    //String[] phones = new String[3];
        //phones[0]="galaxy";
        //phones[1]="lumia";
        //phones[2]="pixel";
    
    Phone[] phones = new Phone[3];  
    phones[0]= galaxy;
    phones[1]= lumia;
    phones[2]= pixel;
    
    // dont work System.out.println(Arrays.oString(phones));
    
    }
}
```

I want to write a loop, that will call the phone.showDetails() method from the phone's array, but I can't find a way to do it. There's a problem with data type conversion or sth.

I want to achieve a loop, that will call:
galaxy.showDetails, then lumia.showDetails() and pixel.showDetails();

Comment: How would you write the loop if instead of a `Phone` array it was an `int` or `String` array?

Comment: `for (Phone phone : phones) phone.showDetails();`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every element and print its details.

```
for (Phone phone: phones){
    phone.showDetails();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your big issue is your phone class doesn't override `toString()`, so all youre going to see is memory address space.  Do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Phone [id=" + id + ", brand=" + brand + ", model=" + model + ", cameraResolution="
                + cameraResolution + "]";
}
```

As for looping through, there are lots of ways you can do this, but the easiest:

```
for (Phone phone : phones) {
    System.out.println(phone);
}
```

Comment: toString() doesn't return the memory address by default. Rather you would see the hascode if you don't overwrite it. Source: [Object.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)

Comment: You're probably right. I've been doing a lot of Go recently, and that either prints out a memory address or raw bytes.